# How to identify locate error like: Error: Unexpected '!'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

Got this error in my React / Next.js app:

```
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: Unexpected '!'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
    at makeWebpackError (/Users/janoskukoda/Workspace/snoopyon/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:308185)
    at /Users/janoskukoda/Workspace/snoopyon/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:105236
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/janoskukoda/Workspace/snoopyon/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28771), <anonymous>:34:1)
-- inner error --
Error: Unexpected '!'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
```

Code in `bundle5` is approximatelly here:

```
HookCodeFactory{constructor(v){this.config=v;this.options=undefined;this._args=undefined}create(v){this.init(v);let E;switch(this.options.type){case"sync":E=new Function(this.args(),'"use strict";\n'+this.header()+this.contentWithInterceptors({onError:v=>`throw ${v};\n`,onResult:v=>`return ${v};\n`,resultReturns:true,onDone:()=>"",rethrowIfPossible:true}));break;case"async":E=new Function(this.args({after:"_callback"}),'"use strict";\n'+this.header()+this.contentWithInterceptors({onError:v=>`_callback(${v});\n`,onResult:v=>`
```

right here: `new Function` but there is no `!` here. How can I debug, locate this error?